# Can't install PHPExcel

Tags: php, pear, phpexcel

I'm trying to install the PHPExcel library on an Ubuntu server.
I executed the following commands in the command line:

```
pear channel-discover pear.pearplex.net
pear install pearplex/PHPExcel
```

The channel was install but the instakll generates an error:

```
pearplex/PHPExcel requires PHP extension "zip" (version >= 1.8.0), installed version is 1.4.0
No valid packages found
install failed
```

Then I did a safe-upgrade:

```
aptitude safe-upgrade
```

and when I check PHP, I see this (Zip version 2.0.0):
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: I rebooted the server, the issue remains.

Comment: check that the cli version of PHP is using the same(ish) configuration as the in-webserver version. There can be multiple .ini files, and it's possible the cli version is pointing at zip 1.4 and the in-server at 2.0

Comment: I have 3 php.ini files on the server: etc/php5/apache2/php.ini, etc/php5/cgi/php.ini and etc/php5/cli/php.ini. I compared them and the only difference is cgi.fix_pathinfo. with is 1 for the cgi version and 0 for the other 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$ php -m
```

to see if the zip extension is there on command line.
Then use

```
$ php --ini
```

to find the location of your php.ini file and fix it.